# rest api get / add products to wishlist

Tags: magento2, rest-api, wishlist

REST API for wishlist is it implemented into magento core or do I have to use extensions to see and add items? Can't find nothing about this in their documentation and no tutorials

I was trying with GET v1/wishlist/clientId and many others with no luck.

I am using latest version of magento

Answer (score 0):

You need to try this extension for the rest API for wishlist: https://github.com/mediamanDE/magento-module-wishlist-api

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Wishlist Api you can use. It's tested and working on Magenot 2.3.x:

https://github.com/Armita84/Magento2-Wishlist-API

Regards,